# How to make Isabelle use basic math rules?

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to learn Isabelle:

```
theory test
imports Main
begin

datatype tree = Leaf | Node tree tree

fun nodes :: "tree ⇒ nat" where
"nodes Leaf = 1"|
"nodes (Node x y) = 1 + (nodes x) + (nodes y)"

fun explode :: "nat ⇒ tree ⇒ tree" where
"explode 0 t = t" |
"explode (Suc n) t = explode n (Node t t)"

theorem tree_count: "nodes (explode h l) = 2^h + 2^h * (nodes l) - 1"
  apply(induction h arbitrary: l)
   apply(auto simp add: numeral_eq_Suc)
  done

end
```

However, the theorem is not solved:

```
Failed to finish proof:
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀h l. (⋀l. nodes (explode h l) = Suc (Suc 0) ^ h + Suc (Suc 0) ^ h * nodes l - Suc 0) ⟹
           Suc (Suc 0) ^ h + (Suc (Suc 0) ^ h + Suc (Suc 0) ^ h * (nodes l + nodes l)) - Suc 0 =
           Suc (Suc 0) ^ h + Suc (Suc 0) ^ h + (Suc (Suc 0) ^ h + Suc (Suc 0) ^ h) * nodes l - Suc 0
```

If I'm not mistaken, Isabelle is just not applying x + x = 2*x and a + (b + c) = a + b + c. So I tried adding a lemma to use it with simp:

```
lemma a: "(x:nat) + x = 2*x"
```

But this fails with

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ ⇒ _" and "_ set"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  (∈) x :: ??'a set ⇒ bool
Operand:   nat :: int ⇒ nat
```

I assume that it's just not possible to define the type of a variable in a lemma?

Now I could of course redifine the addition - but I guess that's not really best practice.
What would be the best way to solve the initial problem?

Comment: it is `x :: nat` (`:` is the ascii version of \in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general approaches to find the right lemmas:

1. Use the theorem search, either via the query panel or in the text with `find_theorems`:

   ```
   find_theorems ‹_ * (_ + _)›
   find_theorems name: assoc "_ + _ + _"
   find_theorems ‹2 * ?z = ?z + ?z›
   ```
2. Use sledgehammer.
3. Try the `algebra_simps` collection as suggested by waldelb (There are also `ac_simps`, `algebra_split_simps`, `field_simps`, and `field_split_simps` ).
4. Try to split it up into smaller steps. This helps the `simp` tool, because simplification can work on both sides of the equation and because you can guide it to the right intermediate steps. The example below is a bit too extreme, doing only one rewrite per step. In general, you can just add intermediary steps where the automatic ones fail.

   ```
    theorem tree_count: ‹nodes (explode h l) = 2^h + 2^h * (nodes l) - 1›
    proof (induction h arbitrary: l)
      case 0
      show ‹nodes (explode 0 l) = 2 ^ 0 + 2 ^ 0 * nodes l - 1›
        by simp
    next
      case (Suc h)

      have ‹nodes (explode (Suc h) l)
         = nodes (explode h (Node l l))›
        by (subst explode.simps, rule refl)
      also have "... = 2 ^ h + 2 ^ h * nodes (Node l l) - 1"
        by (subst Suc, rule refl)
      also have "... = 2 ^ h + 2 ^ h * (1 + nodes l + nodes l) - 1"
        by (subst nodes.simps, rule refl)
      also have "... = 2 ^ h + 2 ^ h * (1 + (nodes l + nodes l)) - 1"
        by (subst add.assoc, rule refl)
      also have "... = 2 ^ h + 2 ^ h * (1 + (2 * nodes l)) - 1"
        by (subst mult_2, rule refl)
      also have "... = 2 ^ h + (2 ^ h * 1 + 2 ^ h * (2 * nodes l)) - 1"
        by (subst distrib_left, rule refl)
      also have "... = 2 ^ h + (2 ^ h * 1 + 2 ^ h * 2 * nodes l) - 1"
        by (subst mult.assoc, rule refl)
      also have "... = 2 ^ h + (2 ^ h * 1 + 2 ^ Suc h * nodes l) - 1"
        by (subst power_Suc2, rule refl)
      also have "... = (2 ^ h + 2 ^ h * 1) + 2 ^ Suc h * nodes l - 1"
        by (subst add.assoc, rule refl)
      also have "... = (2 ^ h + 2 ^ h) + 2 ^ Suc h * nodes l - 1"
        by (subst mult_1_right, rule refl)
      also have "... = 2 ^ h * 2 + 2 ^ Suc h * nodes l - 1"
        by (subst mult_2_right, rule refl)
      also have "... = 2 ^ Suc h + 2 ^ Suc h * nodes l - 1"
        by (subst power_Suc2, rule refl)
      finally show ?case .
    qed
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`algebra_simps` is a list of common math rules. Adding it solves the problem:

```
apply(auto simp add: numeral_eq_Suc algebra_simps)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).